# Reading and interpreting data from a binary file in Python

Tags: python, binary, bitwise-operators

I want to read a file byte by byte and check if the last bit of each byte is set:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    fh = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'rb')
    try:
        byte = fh.read(1)
        while byte != "":
            if (int(byte,16) & 0x01) is 0x01:
                print 1
            else:
                print 0
            byte = fh.read(1)
    finally:
        fh.close

    fh.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mini_01.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./mini_01.py", line 10, in main
    if (int(byte,16) & 0x01) is 0x01:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xaf'
```

Anyone an idea? I didn't succeed using the struct and the binascii modules.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers before you get *this* working and open a dupe of *that* question ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `ord` instead of `int`:

```
if (ord(byte) & 0x01) == 0x01:
```

Comment: and you really should compare integers with `==`, not by their identities!

Comment: Good point. I thought about it, but didn't change it when I pasted that...fixed.

Answer (score 58):

Try using the [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray) type (Python 2.6 and later), it's much better suited to dealing with byte data. Your `try` block would be just:

```
ba = bytearray(fh.read())
for byte in ba:
    print byte & 1
```

or to create a list of results:

```
low_bit_list = [byte & 1 for byte in bytearray(fh.read())]
```

This works because when you index a `bytearray` you just get back an integer (0-255), whereas if you just read a byte from the file you get back a single character string and so need to use [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) to convert it to an integer.

---

If your file is too big to comfortably hold in memory (though I'm guessing it isn't) then an [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) could be used to create the `bytearray` from a buffer:

```
import mmap
m = mmap.mmap(fh.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
ba = bytearray(m)
```

Comment: +1 for the large file solution, I was saved from much hair-tearing. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
import array

filebytes= array.array('B')
filebytes.fromfile(open("/tmp/test.txt", "rb"))
if all(i & 1 for i in filebytes):
    # all file bytes are odd
```

Another way:

```
fobj= open("/tmp/test.txt", "rb")

try:
    import functools
except ImportError:
    bytereader= lambda: fobj.read(1)
else:
    bytereader= functools.partial(fobj.read, 1)

if all(ord(byte) & 1 for byte in iter(bytereader, '')):
    # all bytes are odd
fobj.close()
```