# using python to send an image over TCP to c# server

Tags: c#, python, image, encoding, tcp

I am working on a project that uses a python script to send an image taken with a webcam to a c# webserver using sockets. I am currently sending strings to the server from the python client using code like:

```
info = bytearray("Text to send", "UTF-8")
socket.send(info)
```

to send data to the c# server and it functions perfectly for text and numbers. I run into an issue when trying to encode the data read from the .bmp into "UTF-8", as trying this returns an error of not being able to encode certain characters into UTF-8.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea of a way to encode this that c# will be able to recognize, or, if there is a better way of trying to implement this process, I am all ears.

A couple of options I have come up with would be to 1 - use something like google drive to save the image to, or an FTP server and then have the c# server retrieve it from there or 2 - create a packet system containing the RGB values and recreating the image from those pixel values on the server.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I have tried sending the file this way

```
 data = bytearray("123456789","UTF-8")
 file = open("image.bmp", "rb")
 data += file.read()
 socket.send(data)
```

and was able to successfully retreive the string "123456789", but the data after this is garbage. I have also implemented sending the size of the file before sending the data and that size number is retrieved fine, but the img data saves as a black bmp.

**Edit 2 :**

Here is the server and client code I am using to try and recreate the image using a memory stream. I the client code is using the process mentioned by hcalves.

**Client**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("localhost", 50839))

with open("image.bmp", "rb") as fd:
    buf = fd.read(1024)
    while (buf):
        sock.send(buf)
        buf = fd.read(1024)
sock.close()
```

**Server**

```
Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
byte[] imgData = new byte[1024];
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Read(imgData,0, 1024);
int counter = 0;
while (stream.DataAvailable)
{
    memstream.Write(imgData, 0, 1024);
    stream.Read(imgData, 0, 1024);
    counter = counter + 1024;
}

memstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite("img.bmp"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = memstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        file.Write(buffer,0,len);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to encode a binary image into a text format? Get the bytearray representing the image data, then send THAT array.

Comment: If for some reason you have something against just sending the raw bytes as is, you could base64-encode it. I'm not really sure what you would gain from this, and it would slow the transport down a bit.

Comment: Will the c# image class be able to interpret base64 byte arrays into images?

Comment: I have tried reading the data as binary and just sending that data, but I have to send string data before that so the data object is of type bytearray and wanted it to append to it correctly.

EDIT: Also have been having trouble getting this binary data interpreted correctly on the c# side, which is why I am trying all this. I orginially was just sending the binary array

Comment: If you're saying: "I need to make a proper HTTP request, and that means sending text headers before the binary body", then the way to do that is FIRST get the headers as text, convert that to a byte array, send those bytes, THEN send the bytes of the image. But trying to implement HTTP yourself is borderline crazy. Use an existing framework/object.

Comment: Really it is just a serial number corresponding to a deviceID, so that I know which device this image is coming from. If you know of a more efficient way I would love to hear it, this is all a learning process for me.

Comment: When you say the data is "garbage"-- what EXACTLY is it? (Screenshot from NetMon or Wireshark would be helpful). Have you verified that file.read() does what you're hoping it does?

Comment: The data gets saved as a bmp which displays a black bmp. The api for Python's built in function open says the first character states which mode r - for read and then a b can be appended to the r to read this in binary mode. then the fileobject method read() returns an string array. I was trying to use bytearray to convert this string array into bytes. Are you getting at there is a better way of reading this file in?

Comment: I was gonna suggest bytes or b64 ... but looks like i was slow to the draw

Comment: The moment you go to text, your file is hosed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943149/reading-and-interpreting-data-from-a-binary-file-in-python for how to load a bytearray from a file without mangling it into text first.

Comment: I know this, that is why I was trying to encode the text from the image data into a bytearray using a certain type of encoding that c# would understand. It understood the UTF-8 encoding, so I was wondering if there was a type of encoding that works with the Image class inside of c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need more than this recipe:

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(("localhost", 50839))

    with open("data.bin", "rb") as fd:
        buf = fd.read(1024)
        while (buf):
            sock.send(buf)
            buf = fd.read(1024)
    sock.close()
```

For practical reasons, you can treat `str` objects (the result of `fd.read`) as raw data, you don't need any further crazy encoding. Just iterate the file and send over the socket. Test by running this server which just echoes to stdout with `python server.py > data2.bin`:

```
import socket
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(("localhost", 50839))
    sock.listen(1)

    client, address = sock.accept()

    buf = client.recv(1024)
    while (buf):
        sys.stdout.write(buf)
        buf = client.recv(1024)

    client.close()
    sock.close()
```

A checksum shows the binary data is sent correctly:

```
% md5 data.bin data2.bin      
MD5 (data.bin) = 8b3280072275badf3e53a6f7aae0b8be
MD5 (data2.bin) = 8b3280072275badf3e53a6f7aae0b8be
```

Your C# server should be able to accept this data as is. If it doesn't work, it's because your server is expecting something in particular, not just raw data.

Comment: I am trying your method of sending the data, I do have to have a number sent right before I send the data, but I took that part out just to get this data sending. I have the c# server that stores the image data into a memorystream right before receiving the next set of 1024 bytes. But I am still getting a format error in the image class, my whole reason for finding a different way of encoding the data.

Comment: It's impossible to have an answer without access to the server code. It can be expecting anything.

Comment: Whats the purpose of "counter" in the C# server code? It's not used anywhere. All in all, the code seems analogous to the Python server I posted, so it's not immediately obvious what's wrong. Maybe there's a bug on the way you write the file? Have you tried writing to stdout instead and testing like I did to confirm the right data is sent over the wire?